# How to change a specific part of a column name to something else

Tags: r, dplyr, rename

I inherited a dataset with 25 column names like this: "vocab_item_0_key", "vocab_item_1_key" all the way through "vocab_item_24_key". This is not intuitive to me.
I would like to change "vocab_item_0_key" to "vocab_item_1_key", and "vocab_item_1_key" to "vocab_item_2_key", and so on.  How do I go about doing this in an efficient way?  I'm open to your suggestions, but if I could learn to do this in dplyr, that would be so helpful.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: While I'm sure there is some interesting way to do this programatically, there are only 25 columns...why not just fix the names in the raw data prior to reading into R? Probably would take less time than typing out the question and waiting for an answer.

Comment: Thanks, but I have another data set with 75~ 100 columns that are like that.  If I can get this to work, I can fix the other data set as well.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have two columns:

```
df <- data.frame(vocab_item_0_key = 1:2,
                 vocab_item_1_key = 2:1)
```

We can specify the names we want:

```
colnames(df) <- paste0("vocab_item_", 1:2, "_key")
```

Now:

```
> df
  vocab_item_1_key vocab_item_2_key
1                1                2
2                2                1
```